# Problem with Charts.js in vue. anyone can help step by step

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vuetify.js

How can I use charts with Charts.js in vue and vuetify? I tried all ways.
Can anyone help me step by step?

```
vue version = 2.6.10
chart.js version = 2.9.3
vue-chartjs = 3.5.0
```

---

```
<template>
    <canvas id="chartRecord" width="100%" height="400"></canvas>
</template>
<script>
    import {Line} from 'vue-chartjs';

    export default Line.extend({
        mounted() {
            this.renderChart({
                labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'GitHub Commits',
                        backgroundColor: '#f87979',
                        data: [40, 20, 12, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40, 20, 12, 11]
                    }
                ]
            })
        }
    })
```

and this is where i want to show my chart
Dashboard.vue

```
<v-card>
            <v-layout wrap>
                <v-flex xs12 md12>
                    <my-chart></my-chart>
                </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
        </v-card>

    <script>
        import MyChart from './../components/Charts/Chart.vue'

        export default {
            components: {
                'my-chart' : MyChart
            }
        }


</script>
```

but i'm getting this error in console 
TypeError: vue_chartjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Line.extend is not a function
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/183/ub2b43v5/websocket.
The connection to ws://localhost:8080/sockjs-node/183/ub2b43v5/websocket was interrupted while the page was loading.

Comment: You'll need to add more details around what help you need; do you want help with anything specific? or just a `hello-world` example would suffice? Either way, would help if you could look at codesandbox or jsfiddle to setup your examples.

Comment: @ta-run 
i editted this. take a look now pls

Comment: where does the `Line.extend` come from? Nothing in documentation about it

Comment: Oh, I see, you're using vue-chartjs version 1.x/2.x syntax in version 3.x - you should read the documentation again - or load 2.x version of the library

Comment: @matinwd Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your implementation.
The docs on the [npm page of vue-chartjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chartjs) will help clear this out.

For one, `vue-chartjs` works only within `.js` files or if you want to use SFCs you should exclude the template tag since vuejs can't merge templates and the mixin (used implicitly by `vue-chartjs`) has a template already.

So your implementation would look something like this,

**MyChart.vue** - remember this file SHOULD NOT have a `<template>` tag.

```
<script>
import { Bar } from "vue-chartjs";

export default {
  extends: Bar,
  mounted() {
    this.renderChart({
      labels: [
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December"
      ],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "GitHub Commits",
          backgroundColor: "#f87979",
          data: [40, 20, 12, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40, 20, 12, 11]
        }
      ]
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <my-chart></my-chart>
</template>
<script>
  import MyChart from 'path/to/component/MyChart'

  export default {
    components: {
       'my-chart': MyChart
    }
  }
</script>
```

I've created a codesandbox for this, you can find the implementation [here](https://5qbpy.csb.app/)